# Launch a sh program at startup attached to a terminal window

Tags: macos, launchd

How is it possible to load (with terminal attached window) sh program at OSx startup ?

I see a lot of article on `launchctl` but it's obviously not possible to open a terminal windows attached to the process. Specifically I am looking to run a specific script which is in the sh file (call for a python program. I have to see the echo / print of the program, so to have a terminal attached to the execution).

Comment: Do you want to run /bin/sh and have a shell to type in or are you looking to run a specific script in the sh language?

Comment: @bmike: I am looking to run a specific script which is in the sh file (call for a python program. I have to see the echo / print of the program, so to have a terminal attached to the execution).

Comment: launchd will allow to write to stdout

Comment: Does it need to run on OS X startup or would it be enough to run it after a user logs in?

Comment: @patrix: It's ok to run after each logs in.

Comment: @Mark: With launchd, the only way I found is to export as a log file but impossible to have a terminal attached for each process. Have you the method to do that ?

Comment: Write to console.app - or when it ends open the file with textedit or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use case is simple enough to just save your script to a file named with the `.command` file extension so that Terminal.app is chosen to open it. It needs to be user executable as well. Simply add that file to the user's Login Items in System Preferences.

The script is invoked with  an `; exit` tacked on to the end so you can see and copy the results before dismissing that window each time you login.

[image]